# Why did Ayesha (RA) not dislike the agony of death?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, death, pain

What is the tafsir of the below Hadith:

> Narrated `Aisha:
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) died while he was between my chest and chin, so I
> **never dislike the death agony** for anyone after the Prophet.
>
> https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4446

Comment: @Shaik Abdullah  My bad... In plain English, I just want to understand the context and intent of her words.

Comment: My English is not so good, and maybe in the given case my Arabic also, but I guess you misunderstood the sentence or even the translator might missed a point. But this requires an investigation which I'm not able to perform right now